Inverted volatility smile OMXS30 Sweden?
I am researching volatility smile for school and have just calculated the implied volatility for OMXS30 call options with different strike prices. However, my OTM options have lower implied volatility then my ITM options. What have I done wrong or can this be right. Should the smile not be the other way?
I am a newbie so all help is truly appreciated.

which listed expiries/ tenors are you considering?

A volatility smile is more often constructed with OTM put and OTM calls (left to right).

As you specifically mentioned that you use call options, the shape of the smile you obtain is probably correct.
For call options ITM means $K < S$ and OTM is $K > S$. Typically equity IVs for $K < S$ are higher than for $K > S$.
However, as mentioned by @KaiSqDist in the comment, it is more usual to use OTM puts ($K < S$) and OTM calls ($K > S$) for IV construction as ITM options are typically less liquid.
Furthermore, for far OTM options you may want to trust the bids more than the asks.
